# How to load test an asynchronous pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, aws-msk

I have the following pipeline in AWS

`API-Gateway -> Lambda -> Kafka(Amazon MSK) -> Consumers`

I need to load test the entire pipeline and each component in the pipeline *(to identify bottlenecks)*

I don't have any prior experience in load testing. So, didn't know where to start. Some blogs mentioned `JMeter` can be used to do the load testing. But later got to know that the pipeline is asynchronous and it can't be done using `JMeter`.

How can I load test the pipeline? Is there any standard way to do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any load testing tool which is capable of sending message to the API gateway and then reading it from Kafka.

When it comes to `JMeter` it's capable of both:

1. API Gateway: [Building a WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html#building)
2. Kafka consumer: [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter)
3. If you want to measure the cumulative duration of the request from API till it gets "consumed" - [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)